# "Simple" way to create and plot raster and overlay it with rolling ball animation in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, draw, raster

Ok my idea might be a little naive. But I basically just wanted to create a raster in python where each pixel has a certain Height value associated with it. Something like a DEM in geographics. Then I wanted to draw a shaded relief based on the information in the Raster. For this I found this link: 
https://www.neonscience.org/create-hillshade-py

I then wanted to drop a "Ball" at a random location and just let it roll in one direction based on the values in the raster. So actually create an animation of a rolling ball overlaid on a hillshade.

There are several issued with that. There is matplotlib, but I don't know if it's possible to plot a raster and at the same time draw something like a ball or a circle and refresh the frame every some milliseconds. Moreover, I don't know it this is possible at all (surely it is, but I don't know if it's for me)

I'm not asking for solutions or anything. Just maybe someone has an idea on how to approach this. How to draw the raster for example. There is turtle, but that doesn't seem to be for rasters. There is also pillow, but I never used it. Questions over questions;) 
Maybe someone understands this stupid idea and has any pointer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pygame.
You can use the command pygame.gfxdraw.pixel(surface,x,y,color).
The color could be of the format (x,x,x) where x is determined by the slope.

The problem is that you have to redraw a part of the window every frame as the ball moves.

If you want a faster program I'm afraid you have to use an other language(like java).

The movement of the ball can be calculated with a vector.
Every frame you need to slow down the ball
(x,y)->(0.9*x,0.9*y).

You also need to give the ball extra speed by calculating the slope parallel with the x axis and calculating the slope parallel with y axis. Then just add the cosin of the slope.